# Use sprintf() to add trailing zeros

Tags: r

There has to be a simple way of doing this and I am overlooking it. But if I have a series of `id` and want to add trailing zeros where the character limit is not reached. I saw this solution on another post but can't seem to find it to link for reference.

```
df$id <- c(2331,29623,311,29623)
```

Doing this gets the leading zero:

```
df$id_new <- sprintf("%05s", df$id)
```

But doing this does not get a trailing zero:

```
df$id_new <- sprintf("%-05s", df$id)
```

**Answer**

Thanks to Richard below, I pulled the `stringr` package and used the following to test:

`df$id_test <- str_pad(df$id, width=5, side="right", pad="0")`

Produced:

```
id_test  
23310  
29623  
31100  
29623
```

Comment: Trailing zeros make it a different number.  Why would sprintf be able to do that?

Comment: Also, you should be using `%d`, but it won't matter for the latter.  You can pad with trailing zeros with `stringi::stri_pad_right(id, 5, "0")`

Comment: you can just multiply the numbers `sprintf("%g", nums*10^(5-nchar(nums)))`

Comment: @RichardScriven "invalid format '%05d'; use format %s for character objects"

Comment: @stark because it is an ID that is being read as a number and all id's should have the same number of characters

Comment: Oh, well then disregard that.  Your example is numeric, not character

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `sprintf()` won't do this.  But the *stringi* package has padding functions that are quick and easy.

```
id <- c(2331, 29623, 311, 29623)

library(stringi)
stri_pad_left(id, 5, 0)
# [1] "02331" "29623" "00311" "29623"
stri_pad_right(id, 5, 0)
# [1] "23310" "29623" "31100" "29623"
```

These functions dispatch directly to C code, so they should be sufficiently efficient.

Comment: Thanks, I pulled `stringr` and used: `df$id_test <- str_pad(df$id, width=5, side="right", pad="0")`

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `sprintf` does that, but you can use `formatC` to do that

```
x <- 123    
formatC(as.numeric(x), format = 'f', flag='0', digits = 2)
[1] "123.00"
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it puts the 0 after the decimal. I need to pad before the decimal.

Comment: `gsub(".", "", formatC(as.numeric(x), format = 'f', flag='0', digits = 2), fixed = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

If we insist - we can fool `sprintf()` into doing  what it doesn't want to do:

```
# Helper function from: stackoverflow.com/a/13613183/4552295
strReverse <- function(x) sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), rev), paste, collapse="")

so_0padr <- function(x, width = 5) {
  strReverse(
    sprintf(
      "%0*d",
      width,
      as.integer(
        strReverse(
          as.character(x)
        )
      )
    )
  )
}
```

**Resulting in**

```
so_0padr(c(2331,29623,311,29623))
[1] "23310" "29623" "31100" "29623"
```